# How to get CPU and memory usage statistics in WIndows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I get CPU and memory usage statistics in Windows Phone 7?

Well any statistics about particular WP7 device would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get memory information IN CODE from the [Device Extended Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941122(VS.92).aspx).
Values of interest are:

```
DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceTotalMemory");
DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage");
DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationPeakMemoryUsage");
```

All of these as longs.

Unfortunately, information about the CPU is not currently available.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable counters by using:

```
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
Microsoft.Phone.Shell.SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
```

There is a good article on how to read the date by [Jeff Wilcox](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/).

There is also a profiler out for Windows Phone 7. It's free if you're using one DLL. You can [download it here](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler/).